# Queue more than 2 jobs in a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, random, parameters

I need to be able to queue more than 2 jobs in a Jenkins pipeline.

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/24918670/8369030 it is suggested to use the [Random String Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Random+String+Parameter+Plugin), how ever I can not find any documentation how to use it.

Alternatively I tried to do it with a random value like showed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/67110959/8369030, how ever this seems only to work in a `Stage` but not in a `Parameter`. Specifically, I always get `null` as default value when doing this:

```
pipeline {
    environment {
        max = 50
        random_num = "${Math.abs(new Random().nextInt(max+1))}"
    }

    parameters {
        string(name: 'JOB_ID', defaultValue: "${env.random_num}",
               description: "Enter a random value to allow more than 2 jobs in the queue")

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

But it does not solve the problem with queues, because the parameter is overridden after execution, not before.

```
max = 50
random_num = "${Math.abs(new Random().nextInt(max+1))}"
println(random_num)

pipeline {
    agent any
    
        parameters {
        string(name: 'rn', defaultValue: random_num,
               description: "Enter a random value to allow more than 2 jobs in the queue")

    }
    
    stages {
        
        stage('Randon number') {
            steps {
                println(random_num)
                println(rn)
            }
        }
        
    }
}


Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] echo
31
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test2
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Randon number)
[Pipeline] echo
31
[Pipeline] echo
25
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Solution:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pul3f.png)